# Spotfire - Diagonal line starting at certain point on y axis with increment of x

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

How to draw a diagonal line on a bar chart which starts from certain point on y-axis and not from origin. and then there should be increment every week.  my x- axis is week column.

Tried line and curves - custom curve